# Writing numbers 1-80 in JavaScript and writing text for certain multiples

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and I am making a webpage for fun. Within the webpage I want to make a script that will write numbers 1 to 80 and within those numbers write text1 for multiples of 3, for multiples of 5 write text 2 and for multiples of 3 and 5 write texts15.

Please can you show me how to go about doing this?

Thanks

Edit:

Yes I have a script that I am playing with but cant get it to work:

```
function myFunction()
{
var x="";
for (var i=1;i<81;i++)
  {
  x=x + i + "<br>";
  }
document.getElementById("Eighty").innerHTML=x;

if (i=i*3)
  {
  x="text";
  }
document.getElementById("Eighty").innerHTML=x;
}
```

}

Comment: This problem smells awfully familiar. Toy Story?

Comment: Have you tried anything? You should post some code

Comment: Back in my days we had other definition of 'fun'...

Comment: @elclanrs - Not sure of the Toy Story reference (I haven't seen it) but this is [FizzBuzz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz)

Comment: @MartinSmith: Yeah it was a long shot lol http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzz_Lightyear

Comment: can you show some sample output you need?

Comment: Note that `i=i*3` is an assignment.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that FizzBuzz is a simple exercise in creating an algorithm that's not *completely* trivial, and should encourage you to poke at your language until you figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a number is divisible by another number by using the modulus operator `%`.

```
c = a % b;
```

This operator returns the remainder of the division `a / b`. If that remainder is zero, than `a` is a multiple of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is practically the [Fizz Buzz test](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?FizzBuzzTest). Finding out the multiples is usually done by finding the remainder. Keep in mind that:

```
nominator / denominator = quotient + (remainder / denominator)

examples:
2 / 2 = 1 + ( 0 / 2 )
3 / 2 = 1 + ( 1 / 2 )
4 / 2 = 2 + ( 0 / 2 )
```

The modulus operator is defined as to find the remainder:

```
nominator mod denominator = remainder

from the examples above:
2 mod 2 = 0
3 mod 2 = 1
4 mod 2 = 0
```

Note that **multiples of 2 have the remainder 0**. The same thing goes with 3:

```
1 mod 3 = 1  --  1 / 3 = 0 + ( 1 / 3 )
2 mod 3 = 2  --  2 / 3 = 0 + ( 2 / 3 )
3 mod 3 = 0  --  3 / 3 = 1 + ( 0 / 3 )
4 mod 3 = 1  --  4 / 3 = 1 + ( 1 / 3 )
5 mod 3 = 2  --  5 / 3 = 1 + ( 2 / 3 )
6 mod 3 = 0  --  6 / 3 = 2 + ( 0 / 3 )
```

The easiest way to find a multiple in Javascript is to use the [remainder (modulus) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators):

```
0 % 2; // = 0
1 % 2; // = 1
2 % 2; // = 0 because 2 is divisible with 2
3 % 2; // = 1
4 % 2; // = 0 because 4 is divisible with 2
```

You can do the same with 3 and 5 if you use the operator to find the remainder. If the result is 0 then it is evenly divisible thus a multiple of the number in question.

As usual; to repeat over a set of integers you use the [for-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and you control the flow inside the loops with [if-statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

Here is a [jsFiddle to get you started](http://jsfiddle.net/Pf6PL/).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement properly, I think you are looking for something like this :

```
function myFunction(){
    var x="";
    for (var i=1;i<81;i++){
        var a = '';
        if (i%3 == 0 && i%5 != 0) a="text1";
        else if (i%5 != 0 && i%5 == 0) a="text2";
        else if (i%3 == 0 && i%5 == 0) a="text3";
        x=(a == '')? (x + i + "<br>"): (x + a + "<br>");
    }
    document.getElementById("Eighty").innerHTML=x;
}
```

Please let me inform.